# Expand powers and simplify the coefficient

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

I am given this problem about congruence, and I would like to verify if my answer is correct (it asks for expanding coefficient and simplify by the given module)

```
(a+b)^2 (mod2)
```

is the answer `a^2 + ab + b^2`?

Thank you

Comment: No.  You need to drop even numbers, that is numbers $\equiv 0\pmod 2$ so you should have gotten $a^2+b^2.$

Comment: Never hurts to try a few simple cases, first, like $a=b=1$.

Comment: The misconception is this : $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$. Going modulo $2$ tells you to remove all explicit multiples of  $2$ from the expression. In particular, you should have landed up with $a^2 + b^2$,  which in fact simplifies to $a+b$ modulo $2$, although that may not be as elementary.